# XAML sizes not accurate

Tags: wpf, xaml

From my understanding, WPF allows the designer to set the size of something (in this case a rectangle) and it will be displayed on screen as exactly that size to the user. For example, this square should display on screen as exactly 1 inch. See [FrameworkElement.Width Property on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.width.aspx).

```
<Rectangle Width="1 in" Height="1 in" Fill="{StaticResource sT}" />
<DrawingBrush AlignmentX="Left" AlignmentY="Top">
<DrawingGroup x:Key="SnellenT">
    <DrawingGroup.Children>
        <GeometryDrawing Brush="Black"
                         Geometry="F1 M0,0 3,0 A 1.5,1.5 90 0 1 3,3 H2 L2,4 3,4 3,5 0,5 0,4 1,4 1,1 0,1 M5,5 " />

        <GeometryDrawing Brush="Black"
                         Geometry="F1 M0,0 5,0 5,5 0,5 0,0" />
</....> --Close all tags
```

On my particular machine (Win 7, 24 in monitor, 1920 x 1080 resolution) the square is slightly larger than 1 inch; 1 1/16 inches. (A 3 inch rectangle is 3 1/8 inches.) If I change resolution on my monitor 1o 1280x720, That 1 inch rectangle changes to 1 9/16 (3 inches to 4 5/8).

Please explain to me why this is. My understanding was that wpf kept the images at the specified size regardless of monitor size or screen resolution. Even on the correct resolution for my monitor size the sizes were off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WPF respects the logical DPI that your OS reports, though that might not always match up to the actual size of your monitor. Your monitor can choose to make bigger or smaller pixels than the standard of 96 DPI, but still report a logical 96 DPI for compatibility.

What WPF adjusts for is the DPI set in Windows, or the "Make it easier to read what's on your screen" option. 100% is 96 DPI, 125% is 120 DPI and 150% is 144 DPI. It should be the same size no matter which of those you pick, but it's really up to your monitor how big it's actually going to end up being.

Answer (score 1):

In WPF, the "in" abbreviation just translates to 96px units. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.height.aspx. Also this answer has a good description of why Windows can't actually accomplish what you would like: https://stackoverflow.com/a/300696/561604.